# Using a member of typedef enum is this possible?

Tags: c, enums, typedef

So I have a typedef enum similar to:

```
typedef enum
{
    CH1,
    CH2,
    CH3
} AIN_Ch_t;
```

This is declared in a separate file.

So in another file I want to use this enum.

Here is what I think should be right:

```
//declare variable of type AIN_Ch_t
AIN_Ch_t channel1;
//use the variable as parameter in function compiler gives error
func1(channel1.CH1);
```

But when I do this - no error:

```
func1(CH1); //no error. compiler likes.
```

Obviously I'm thinking about this all wrong. Can someone clarify? thanks!

Comment: An `enum` *does not have members* in a way as `struct`s or `union`s have. You can't access them as `Type.Member`. You are just using it as `Member`. If you do that, and have all the warning and errors enabled, your compiler will tell you the rest.

Comment: Replace `enum` with `struct` and it works as you expected.

Comment: regarding this line: `func1(channel1.CH1);`  as stated elsewhere, cannot treat a enum as a struct with members.   however, could use this line: `func1(CH1);`

Answer (score 2):

```
func1(channel1.CH1);
```

`enums` don't have members like structure . What you do is incorrect. What you can do is this -

```
AIN_Ch_t channel1;
channel1=CH1;   
func1(channel1);
```

Or the second way as you do-

```
func1(CH1);             // directly pass CH1 to function
```

[You can refer here to know about `enums`.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

Answer (score 0):

Enumeration constants like `CH1` are regular identifiers, unlike `struct` or `union` members.  They live in the same name space as variable and function names.

This means that:

- You do not refer to enumeration constants using an *`instance`*`.`*`constant`* syntax like `struct` or `union` members;
- No two `enum` types in the same program may share enumeration constant names;
- No `enum` type may use a constant name that's also used as a function or variable name.

Basically, `enum`s are a fancy way of doing

```
const int CH1 = 0;
const int CH2 = 1;
...
```

You can fake namespaces by using a prefix:

```
typedef enum AIN_Ch { AIN_CH1, AIN_CH2, AIN_CH3 } AIN_Ch_t;
```

It ain't pretty, but it does the job.